# Should I normalize distributions when I concat two kind of neural networks

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, normalization

I concatenated LSTM networks and FC networks however the result of the concatenated networks is not good.
So, I recorded histograms of each output of networks and found out distributions of both networks are different.
In this case, Should I normalize each network's output before I concat those?
If it is, what kind of normalization should I apply?
I applied the batch normalization for each output but the result is very same as before.
Thanks in advance.